# Unexpected result in Javascript Kata on Codewars

Tags: javascript, function

Essentially I'm supposed to build a function that will give me the same output as the following test cases;

```
Test.assertSimilar(testit(0,1), 1, "")
Test.assertSimilar(testit(1,2), 3, "")
Test.assertSimilar(testit(10,20), 30, "")
//a*b?
Test.assertSimilar(testit(1,1), 1, "")
Test.assertSimilar(testit(1,3), 3, "")
```

This is what I've come up with;

```
function testit(a,b){
  return b >= (2*a) ? a+b : a*b;
}
```

Essentially the logic is if b is greater than or equal to 2a than add a and b if not multiply a by b.
**BUT the very last test case is returning 4 and I have no idea why that would happen.**  I'm just curious what I'm missing here or if there's some underlying principle I don't know of causing this to happen. Logically it seems like it should return 1*3 = 3.

Comment: Are there more test cases you can share? I don't quite understand how you can have your last line `Test.assertSimilar(testit(1,3), 3, "")` and also another test that is essentially `Test.assertSimilar(testit(1,3), 4, "")` ? At least that's what it sounds like based on your comments

Comment: by your code it's saying `3 >= (2*1)` so return `1 + 3`

Comment: please add the link to the kata.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the test cases, the logic you describe does not hold for the last testcase. Indeed 3 is greater than twice 1, so it would be an addition, and 1+3 is indeed 4. So you'll have to find another logic.

Although these test cases are not enough to really know for sure what the logic is, they do hold for a simple bit-wise OR operation:

```js
const testit = (a, b) => a | b;

test(0,1,    1)
test(1,2,    3)
test(10,20, 30)
test(1,1,    1)
test(1,3,    3)

function test(a, b, expect) {
    let result = testit(a, b);
    console.log(`testit(${a},${b}) = ${result}, expect ${expect}`);
}
```